# Generate Dotnet GRPC Client code Without CsProj

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, grpc

It's possible to use `protoc` to generate dotnet code in a way that doesn't require a csproj or solution:

```
protoc -I=$SRC_DIR --csharp_out=$DST_DIR $SRC_DIR/addressbook.proto
```

Is it possible to do something similar to generate the code for a grpc client/server stub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you just need the gRPC plugin, which you can download in the `Grpc.Tools` package.

You then use:

```bash
protoc --grpc_out=$DST_DIR --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=$GRPC_PLUGIN $SRC_DIR/addressbook.proto`
```

where `GRPC_PLUGIN` is the path to `grpc_csharp_plugin.exe` (or the equivalent binary for your OS) from the NuGet package. Note that the NuGet package is just a zip file really, so you can script downloading it and unzipping it should you wish.

As an example of doing this in a shell script, you could look at [the generateprotos.sh script in gax-dotnet](https://github.com/googleapis/gax-dotnet/blob/main/generateprotos.sh) - that also gives an example of specifying that you want a `.g.cs` suffix.